# Как сгладить UI и остальные объекты в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытался сглаживать в Quality Anti Aliasing, но не помогает..

[image: Лесинка :D]
[image: Настройка]

Comment: ты запускал откомпиленную игрушку или из эдитора?

Comment: из эдитора запускал

Comment: А какая вообще версия Unity? Если это 2018+, то, возможно, это связано с rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

1. <s>не все эфекты отображаются в эдиторе. Некоторые только в полноценном рантайме. На счет антиалиасинга -- не уверен</s> У АА в этом плане все ок оказалось
2. Камера и плеер должны быть настроены на  forward rendering.
3. <s>Антиалиасинг не работает на мобильных устройствах если что</s>  Оказалось что работает, но желательно ставить не больше 2йки на мобильных.
4. Возможно может влиять  "Allow HDR" в настройках камеры. (все зависит
   от того куда ты билдишь проэкт, но попробуй и так и так).
5. так же поизучай вот эту страницу: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingPaths.html может, еще что найдешь
6. Так же это может быть хардварной проблемой. Это воспроизводится на другом железе? (запускать в Fantastic)

Comment: 1 - АА должен работать в эдиторе, именно в play камере, а не в scene view, 3 - неправда, 4 - hdr никакого отношения к AA не имеет

Comment: 4 относится к проэктам для браузера. Гугление показало что там бывают проблемы которые именно так могут решится. 3. - перепроверил. Ты прав

Comment: HDR в браузерках - это конечно тот еще изврат, в такие дебри я не лез, вполне возможно, что там это как-то влияет)

Comment: Спасибо попробую, проект для Win.